# How to express "just" in "just opened last April" without using "ne ... que"?

Tags: expressions, indications-de-temps, adverbes

> Ce restaurant japonais au cœur de la ville de Kyôto a ouvert ses portes en avril dernier **encore**, mais il est rapidement devenu si ridiculement populaire qu'il faut maintenant une réservation une année à l'avance !

Ou bien :

> En avril dernier **encore**, ce restaurant japonais au cœur de la ville de Kyôto a ouvert ses portes, mais il est rapidement devenu si ridiculement populaire qu'il faut maintenant une réservation une année à l'avance !

Cette phrase fait partie d'un courriel que j'ai envoyé. Je me doute que l'on ne peut décemment pas utiliser la locution restrictive « ne ... que » dans « n'a ouvert ses portes qu'en avril dernier ». L'adverbe « encore » est la seule alternative qui me soit venue à l'esprit, mais je n'en suis pas sûr.

À propos, vaut-il mieux employer « et » au lieu de « mais » comme conjonction après « encore » ?

Comment: Ton utilisation de *encore* me semble complètement fausse. C'est généralement *seulement* ou *juste* qu'on veut utiliser pour *just*. *He has just arrived* = *Il vient juste d'arriver* = *Il vient seulement d'arriver*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

L'utilisation de *encore* ne me semble pas correcte.

La phrase pourrait être remplacée par

> Ce restaurant japonais, au coeur de la ville de Kyôto **n'a** ouvert ses portes **qu'en** Avril dernier mais est devenu si rapidement populaire qu'il faut maintenant une réservation une année à l'avance !

OU

> Ce restaurant japonais, au coeur de la ville de Kyôto, **vient tout juste** d'ouvrir ses portes en Avril dernier mais ...

OU

> Ce restaurant japonais, au coeur de la ville de kyôto, ouvert **seulement** en Avril dernier, est devenu si rapidement populaire qu'il faut maintenant une réservation une année à l'avance !

Comment: De dire « venir de ... », ça ne m'a pas effleuré, mais je me demande juste si dix-huit mois ne sont pas trop loin pour que l'on emploie « venir de ... » ? Merci.

Comment: J'ai ajouté une autre possiblité. C'est vrai que " venir de ..." peut sembler être utilisé pour quelque chose de très proche. Cela se discute.. je ne saurai pas répondre

Comment: @LUNA En effet, il y a une connotation un peu trop forte de proximité temporelle à mon goût également... Mais les 2 autres propositions n'ont pas ce problème.

Comment: @LUNA « Avril dernier », c'est il y a six mois, pas dix-huit mois. Dix-huit mois, ça serait « en avril de l'année dernière ».

Comment: @Gilles Merci de me l'avoir fait remarquer !

Answer (score 2):

Voilà comment je modifierais cette phrase. Utiliser "ne … que" ne pose aucun problème.

> Ce restaurant japonais situé au cœur de la ville de Kyôto **n'a** ouvert ses portes **qu'en** avril dernier mais il est devenu depuis si populaire qu'il faut maintenant réserver une année à l'avance !

Answer (score 1):

En complément des autres réponses, j'ajouterai que ton utilisation erronée  de *encore* est peut-être due à une confusion avec la négation (*not yet*) :

> Ce restaurant japonais au cœur de la ville de Kyôto **n'avait pas encore** ouvert ses portes en avril dernier, mais il est rapidement devenu si ridiculement populaire qu'il faut maintenant une réservation une année à l'avance !

Alors qu'à l'affirmative, on utilisera *seulement* ou *juste* comme d'autres l'ont répondu.

On utilise souvent la négation avec *encore* pour situer la proximité entre deux événements :

> Je n'étais pas encore descendu de la voiture que le chauffeur a redémarré !